# Show the number(count) of each list item by the total number of items in flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, count, items

I want to display the number of each item which is inside the list to a Card, I found some example which they said you should do it with a for() loop, and i did just that but the number isn't incrementing at all can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
              child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                itemScrollController: itemController,
                itemCount: selectedChallenge.contestantsList.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                  final sortedList = selectedChallenge.contestantsList
                    ..sort((itemOne, itemTwo) =>
                        itemTwo.points.compareTo(itemOne.points));

                  final data = sortedList[index];

                  // My for loop
                  for (var i = 0;
                      i < selectedChallenge.contestantsList.length;
                      i++,) {
                    return Card(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: Text('${i}'),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 35,
                                width: 35,
                                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                  imageUrl: data.avatar,
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 12,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                data.firstName + ' ' + data.lastName,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),

                          Text(data.points.toString()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
```

What I got:

[image]

What I want:

][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the index of your builder and remove the for loop

```
ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                itemScrollController: itemController,
                itemCount: selectedChallenge.contestantsList.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                  final sortedList = selectedChallenge.contestantsList
                    ..sort((itemOne, itemTwo) =>
                        itemTwo.points.compareTo(itemOne.points));

                  final data = sortedList[index];

                 return Card(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                child: Text('${index + 1}'),
                              ),
// rest of the code
```

Another suggestion is to sort the list first before building it.

```
// sort the list first in a method or something
    final sortedList = selectedChallenge.contestantsList
                        ..sort((itemOne, itemTwo) =>
                            itemTwo.points.compareTo(itemOne.points));

// build it
    ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                    itemScrollController: itemController,
                    itemCount: sortedList.length,
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its help to you.

declare one int variable

```
int index = 1;
```

Your Widget.

```
Text(
  (index + 1).toString(),
 ),
```

Whole Widget.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                                  top: 18, bottom: 18),
                              child: Text("Powered By:",
                                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        ListView.builder(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: 10,
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                              return Card(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  elevation: 0.4,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                                  ),
                                  child: Container(
                                      child: ListTile(
                                          leading: Expanded(
                                            child: Text(
                                              (index + 1).toString(),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          title: Text(
                                            "Coconut Oil",
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black87,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                          subtitle: Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Icon(Icons.linear_scale,
                                                  color: Colors.greenAccent),
                                              Text("Go Green!",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black87))
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                           )));
                            })
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

Your result screen like->[image]